# Using system tables in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to use the following SQL statements in a VB.NET app:

```
select * from information_schema.parameters
where specific_name='GetTaskEvents'

SELECT * 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE 
    ROUTINE_NAME= 'GetTaskEvents'
```

I spoke to the DBA about it today and he seemed unkeen, but did not give a reason.  Is it bad practice to do this?

I want to be able to do something like this

```
public sub Delete()
'loop around about ten databases
'Call the delete function in each of the databases (check that the stored procedure exists first)
'Each database has different output parameters.  Deal with them differently e.g. if there is an email parameter, then email the person to say the record was deleted.
End Sub
```

The reason for this is so that I can treat each database the same.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as final result?

Comment: What if another developer or DBA adds a `delete` proc that you *shouldn't* be calling?  Delete is a destructive operation.  You should really only be calling it if you know what it will do.

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter, I have edited the question.  Does this help?

Comment: Did you ask the DBA what his reasons were?

Comment: @Amy, yes I agree.  I will call the stored procedure something else, but the same in each database.

Comment: No, I will ask tomorrow.

Comment: @Amy, do you have an opinion on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what the stored procedure *is* but not sure what the parameters are - a better way to use [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) method to get the number of parameters as well as their types and names.

*UPDATE* Here is a basic usage example in VB.NET

```
Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand("SpName", oConnObject)
oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(oCommand)
```

At this point `oCommand.Parameters` collection will be filles with parameters for "SpName"

Comment: Nice, I like that as well. +1

Comment: @w0051977 glad it was helpful. Please check as answered if suggestion was useful.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? I should then be able to mark this question as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 Updated my answer with a basic example. Feel free to Google for more advanced examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters+example

Comment: ? My answer was to use CommandBuilder, you asked for an example, I provided one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I asked how to get the names of the parameters i.e. if there is an output parameter called "return", then I want to store the value "return" in a string.  Thanks.

Comment: Well unfortunately I cannot write entire code for you. I mentioned in my answer that `oCommand.Parameters` is a collection of parameters. You should know what SqlParameter is and how to loop thru a collection.

Comment: I have got it now.  param.ParameterName was what I was looking for.  I didn't see your edit.  I think my PC used a cached version of this webpage from this morning.

Comment: No, I didn't add it. I assumed you would see it for yourself since you did work with SqlParameters before.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice should come down to what kind of risk you are willing to expose your company to in order to get the type of data you need.  Risk / benefit analysis.

In this case the risk I see is that you are making your code depend on Microsofts behind the scenes system tables and schemas.  These do tend to change from version to version.  So, a move from sql 2018 to 2021 for example could break your compiled code.  *Aside from the risks outlined in comments about calling procs you don't understand the effect of.*

So, to reduce that risk you could put your code in a stored proc so that you can easily update it without having to recompile code if and when the system schema does change.  There are other ways to reduce the other risks identified but that is how I analyze "best practice".

Comment: Yes, I agree that best practice is a subjective term. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace System.Data:

DbConnection + DbCommand + IDataReader (SqlConnection + SqlCommand for SQL Server)

Comment: Thanks, but how does that answer my question?